# How to apply same style on all buttons in windows form

Tags: winforms, windows-forms-designer

i have multiple buttons in my windows form application , and i want to apply some style on `btnhover` like this

```
private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
  button1.BackColor = Color.GhostWhite;
}
private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
}
```

i want to put this style at one place and i want that it atuomatically apply on all buttons in my form . how can i do this , Please help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to put this in one place and have auto-styled forms, that would be its own class:

```
class ButtonStyledForm : Form
{
    protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnControlAdded(e);

        if (e.Control.GetType() == typeof(Button))
        {
            e.Control.MouseEnter += button_MouseEnter;
            e.Control.MouseLeave += button_MouseLeave;
        }
    }    

    protected override void OnControlRemoved(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnControlRemoved(e);

        if (e.Control.GetType() == typeof(Button))
        {
            e.Control.MouseEnter -= button_MouseEnter;
            e.Control.MouseLeave -= button_MouseLeave;
        }
    }

    private void button_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var c = (Button)sender;
        c.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        c.BackColor = Color.GhostWhite;
    }

    private void button_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var c = (Button)sender;
        c.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    }
}
```

Then inherit from this class instead of `Form`.

Answer (score 0):

This won't *automatically* apply it to new buttons that are added to the form, but it will apply it to all existing buttons as I suspect is what you really want to do:

```
partial class MyForm
{
    foreach(var b in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
        b.MouseEnter += button1_MouseEnter;
        b.MouseLeave += button1_MouseLeave;
    }
}
```

Note you will have to change your event handlers to use `sender` instead of directly using `button1`, like:

```
private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var c = (Button)sender;
    c.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
    c.BackColor = Color.GhostWhite;
}

private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var c = (Button)sender;
    c.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
}
```