# overloading button in visual studio c#.net

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have a 54 buttons a flat style = flat, and I manually designed each one of them with an image on mouse hover and mouse leave w/c is all of them has the same design. What should I do to make it more easier than doing the code of mousehover and mouseleave each button.

Comment: What framework are you using? Windows Forms? WPF? Silverlight? If you are using Forms, then this is a possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090639/how-to-apply-same-style-on-all-buttons-in-windows-form

Comment: You could set the button up as a custom control with the mouse enter and leave behavior. Expose the hover and normal image paths in the constructor or as public props.

Comment: I am using windows form application sir.

Comment: I strongly recommend WPF instead of winforms. It has support for `Styles` and `Templates` that you can use to customize the appearance and visual styles of any UI element reuse throughout the application. winforms is a really old technology that doesn't support a deep level of customization, and is not recommended for any new projects, only to maintain legacy applications.

Comment: If I modify the default button with my own style do this affect to other buttons too which is not the same design with my 54 buttons? This is my college project sir. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't specified, I'll assume winforms.

So you've got 54 buttons and you've manually code up presumably 108 methods (54 for mouse enter & 54 for mouse leave)

What you could do is create an object to hold button->image info, and store it all in a dictionary. Key it by button Id. i.e.

```
public class ButtonImageInfo 
{  
     public string ButtonId {get;set;}
     public string MouseEnterImage {get;set;}
     public string MouseLeaveImage {get;set;}
}

// ...
public Dictionary<string, ButtonImageInfo> _dict = new ...
_dict.Add("Button1", new ButtonImageInfo ("Button1", "Image1Enter", "Image1Leave"));
///    ... etc...
```

That would allow you to code up one OnMouseEnter & one OnMouseLeave methods and apply them to every button.

You would then just grab the correct image based on the sender Id.

```
private void MouseLeaveEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Button b = sender as Button;
     if(b != null)
     { 
          string id = b.Id;
          //Do Something with _dict[id].MouseLeaveImage
     }
  }

  private void MouseEnterEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Button b = sender as Button;
     if(b != null)
     { 
          string id = b.Id;
          //Do Something with _dict[id].MouseEnterImage
     }
  }
```

Comment: sir im done adding a class in my form ButtonImageInfo and my question is where should i code this "private void MouseLeaveEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)"? It should be add in my form.cs?

Comment: yep. In the same place as your existing mouse enter/mouse leave methods.

Comment: You mean all i need is to click one button and modify its mouser enter/mouse leave methods and put all my buttons there so that it will be in one method. Can you gave me and example sir. Sir can you create me a class in buttonimageinfo because I encounter problem so that I can add existing file in my form directly.